# How to arrage RTE button in TYPO3 Page TSConfig?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am using TYPO3 6.2.17 I try to group button in RTE of TYPO3 Content with

```
RTE.default.keepButtonGroupTogether = 1
```

But it seems wrong.

Any Idea? Thanks